# Good free html editor with shortcuts for <p>'s

Tags: html, editor

Hi can anyone recommend a good free html editor.

I want something that will let me wrap sections of code in `<p>` tags with a shortcut for example.  It would make my life easier.

I'm a developer so I want something where I'll be writing most of the html by hand.

Thanks for the help,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/) is just great for beginners, and has this functionality.

Comment: Just in case you want everything else that can go with Visual Web Developer, you can use the web platform installer (http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and quickly download the tools.

Comment: Might want to add that it´s free as in beer.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has this functionality. It works with many languages including HTML. Get it from http://netbeans.org/ Its free

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs' html-mode you're typing along, hit C-c RET, type your paragraph, hit C-c / to close the paragraph, and keep on hacking.

You can find this tip, and many more, [here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_html.html).

Comment: You can actually write a function to close any previous tag when you type "</". That said, I doubt I'd recommend Emacs unless you were planning on learning LISP too. Emacs isn't really an editor; it's a language for succinctly expressing editors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bluefish. This is a free software text editor. The "Auto tag closing" is include in the software : http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/manual/ch07s02.html

Official website : http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, but with shortcuts for the most common XHTML blocks: [Rejbrand Text Editor](http://english.rejbrand.se/rteditor).

You press Alt+Enter to insert `<p></p>`; any selection will be included inside the tags. Ctrl+Enter inserts `<br />`, Ctrl+I inserts `<li></li>` etc. Ctrl+n inserts `<hn></hn>`.

Answer (score 0):

Programmer's Notepad 2 gives you the easiness you're asking for, plus it also writes for ALL other programming languages with syntax highlighting to ALL and it adds the closing tags of HTML for you and all the optimizing stuff. Plus it is FREE. It also is VERY portable being only 2.4 megabytes! You can download it from here:

[Programmers Notepad Download Latest Version](http://www.pnotepad.org/download/)